# Perform LIKE operation for each element of a GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a subquery in Mysql that performs aggregation using the GROUP_CONCAT function for an attribute of the join table (1-N relationship)

```sql
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS list 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.x_id = t1.id  
GROUP BY t1.id
```

that returns the following content:

| id | list |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value-1,value_2,x-value-1 |
| 2 | value-1 |
| 3 | null |

Now in the main query, I need to perform some kind of `LIKE` operation that maps through every single element of the set, and for example the following statement:

```sql
WHERE list LIKE "x-value%"
```

should return the element with the id 1, and its returning an empty result set.

Any ideas?

**Response to Barmar answer:**

I have not used the LIKE in the sub-query because I have a feature that can negative filter the names where I use FIND_IN_SET, that's why I am doing the group in the first place. For example if I didn't have done the grouping, would get the following result:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value-1 |
| 1 | value_2 |
| 1 | x-value-1 |
| 2 | value-1 |
| 3 | null |

And then if I didn't group it, and wanted the id's without the value `value-1`

```sql
WHERE value != "value-1"
```

it would return

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value_2 |
| 1 | x-value-1 |

Meaning I would get the id 1, even if it has the value `value-1`

Comment: There's no way to loop over a comma-separated list in a query. Why not put the `LIKE` in the subquery?

Comment: let me update the issue why I have not done that, but thanks!

Comment: The pattern should be `%x-value%`.

Comment: You could use a regexp: `RLIKE '(^|,)x-value'`

Comment: like instead of double inverted commas use single inverted commas?

Comment: You could try to use FIND_IN_SET, something like "WHERE FIND_IN_SET('x-value-1',list) > 0"

Comment: @JonasMetzler He doesn't want an exact match, he wants to match anything beginning with `x-value`.

Comment: @Barmar but I wanted specifically that the string started with `x_value` and starting with the wildcard at the beggining, that would not be possible to ensure. About the regex, have to test it  but thanks!

Comment: @JonasMetzler tried that but FIND_IN_SET doesn't support wildcards :/

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression to match `x-value` at either the beginning or after a comma.

```
WHERE list REGEX '(^|,)x-value'
```

But it would be better to do this in another subquery.

```
SELECT t1.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name) AS list
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.x_id
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT x_id
    FROM table2
    WHERE name LIKE 'x-value%'
) ON t1.id = t2.x_id
```

There's no need to use `LEFT JOIN` since you don't need any results that have no match in `table2` (since they won't match `x-value%`).

You need to join twice: Once to get all the names for each ID, and a second time to filter to just the IDs that have `x-value%` in any of the names.